# Group incoming vertices of a vertex group by edge label

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

Currently, I have the following query in Java:

`GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> vertex = g.V(vertex).inV().valueMap();`

Which returns the incoming vertices to the vertex, basically is a huge list, and one vertex can have two edges to the other one, so there's no way to know which edge is, so I would like to know how I can group those by edge label ( the edges have no properties) and so I can know which vertex belongs to what edge, I was doing :

`g.V(vertex).in('contributeTo').valueMap()` but this would mean I'd need to query edge by edge which is not scalable at all.

Any ideas on how I can do that or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
g.V(vertex).inE().group().by(label()).by(outV().valueMap().fold())
```